# Scrapy handle closespider timeout in middleware

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, timeout, middleware

I have multiple scrapers which I want to put a time limit on. The `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` does the job and it returns
`finish_reason: closespider_timeout`.

I want to intercept this and use the `logging` library to log an `error`. how can I do this? should it go in a middleware?

Answer (score 0):

`CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` is handled by [the `CloseSpider` extension](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider) which works by scheduling a Twisted task that closes the spider after the time has passed. It's unclear to me if you want to keep this behavior or override it.

If you want to override it without disabling this extension you can subclass it and change the code it schedules in `spider_opened()` to the one you want.

If you want to keep it while adding your own handling you can either do the same subclassing or just subscribe to the `spider_closed` signal.